# Zeppelin Twitter Streaming Example Not Working

Tags: twitter, spark-streaming, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run Twitter Streaming Example in Zeppelin. After I searched around, I added "org.apache.bahir:spark-streaming-twitter_2.11:2.0.0" into Spark Interpreter. So I can make the first part work, as in:

[Apache Zeppelin 0.6.1: Run Spark 2.0 Twitter Stream App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447847/apache-zeppelin-0-6-1-run-spark-2-0-twitter-stream-app)

Now I am trying to add the second half as:

```
case class Tweet(createdAt:Long, text:String, screenName:String)
twt.map(status=>
  Tweet(status.getCreatedAt().getTime()/1000, status.getText(), status.getUser().getScreenName())
).foreachRDD(rdd=>
  rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("tweets")
)
```

Now I got the error:

```
<console>:56: error: not found: type StreamingContext
       val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
                     ^
<console>:56: error: not found: value Seconds
       val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
                                          ^
<console>:61: error: not found: value Seconds
       val twt = tweets.window(Seconds(60))
```

Actually I added the case line, I got the above error. I really had no idea what happened here.

Any one has any clue here?

Here are details
Spark: 2.0.0
Zeppelin: 0.6.2

Thanks a lot.

=====================================================================

```
// All codes for your reference:
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import java.io.File
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import sys.process.stringSeqToProcess
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

// ********************************* Configures the Oauth Credentials for accessing Twitter ****************************
def configureTwitterCredentials(apiKey: String, apiSecret: String, accessToken: String, accessTokenSecret: String) {...}

// ***************************************** Configure Twitter credentials ********************************************
val apiKey = ...
val apiSecret = ...
val accessToken = ...
val accessTokenSecret = ...
configureTwitterCredentials(apiKey, apiSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

//  ************************************************* The logic itself *************************************************
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
val twt = tweets.window(Seconds(60))
twt.print
// above codes work correctly

// If added the following line, it failed with the above error
case class Tweet(createdAt:Long, text:String, screenName:String)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I have no idea why moving the import statements from the top to right before the new StreamingContext fixed it, but it did.

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming._  //moved here from top
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._  //moved here from top
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))  //existing
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Using the FQCNs worked ok, so I ended up using that as a workaround.